# Google Sheets Script Replace Value of getUsername() with Initials

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have little experience with code so I've made this script based off of what I've found around the internet. What it does currently is when a cell in Column A is edited, Column E gets filled with a timestamp, and Column G gets filled with the username of the editor of Column A. I then have this arrayfunction: `=ArrayFormula(IF(G2:G = "username1", SUBSTITUTE(G2:G, "username1", "initials1"), IF(G2:G = "username2", SUBSTITUTE(G2:G, "username2", "initials2"),""))` which fills Column E with the initials of the editor (only 2 editors right now) with Column G as a helper column.

My current method is slow and doesn't really allow me to scale up to more editors. How can I change my script so that instead of filling Column G with a username, I can directly fill Column E with initials and forgo having to use Column G as a helper.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var i = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2'].indexOf(sheet.getName());
  if (i > -1 && e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername());
  }
}
```

Comment: [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) only has one method `getEmail()`. I don't see a `getUserName()` method

Comment: That's weird, it works for me. For example getEmail() returns "email@gmail.com" while getUsername() returns "email"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can create a json object with mappings between emails and initials:

```
const initials = {
    "email1":"initials1",
    "email2":"initials2",
    "email3":"initials3"
};
```

and then get the initials like that:

`e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(initials[Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()]);`

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const initials = {
    "email1":"initials1",
    "email2":"initials2",
    "email3":"initials3"
  };
  
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var i = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2'].indexOf(sheet.getName());
  if (e.range.getValue()!='' && i > -1 && e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(initials[Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()]); 
  }
}
```

**Side Notes:**

Indeed `Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()` does not seem to be supported on `V8`, but if it works for you (you use `Rhino` maybe) then use my solution and replace `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` with `Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()`. The point of my answer is to use a json object to do the mappings. Also try `Session.getActiveUser()` which is equivalent to `Session.getEffectiveUser()` for simple triggers.

Comment: [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) only has one method `getEmail()`

Comment: @Cooper thanks, true. I was just using the solution of OP.

Comment: @Cooper hmm not sure. But the point of my approach is to use a json object to do the mappings. The OP is free to select the method that returns the username. As far as I can tell he says that he gets it.

Comment: I have one more question, the onEdit(e) triggers both when I write something in a cell and delete something in a cell. Is there a way to make it only trigger when I write something?

Comment: @Marios Ah, I see what you did there. I was expecting a replacement for onEdit(e) or something. Thanks.

Comment: @Marios Everything is working as intended so far, so that's good. With the current script, it triggers when a cell in Column 1 is edited and not empty. How can I make it so that the script only triggers if both Column 1 and Column 2 are edited and are not empty?

Comment: @flippitydipjfnor Unfortunately, stack overflow does not allow for follow up questions. Please consider posting a new question regarding the modification. Sorry for the inconvenience.